# Correct way to install psql without full Postgres on macOS?

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql, macos-sierra

[Official page](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx) do not mention such case. But many users need only `psql` without a local database (I have it on AWS). Brew do not have `psql`.

Comment: Why do you think there exists a "correct way" to do this, given that you linked to the official download page, which says there isn't a way?

Comment: For those on MacPorts, here's what I did: https://superuser.com/questions/305031/how-do-i-install-the-postgres-command-line-client-psql-on-os-x-using-macports

Comment: @Ssswift It doesn't say there isn't a way, just doesn't say there is a way.

Answer (score 875, accepted):

You could also use homebrew to install libpq.

```
brew install libpq
```

This would give you psql, pg_dump and a whole bunch of other client utilities without installing Postgres.

Unfortunately since it provides some of the same utilities as are included in the full `postgresql` package, brew installs it "keg-only" which means it isn't in the PATH by default.  Homebrew will spit out some information on how to add it to your PATH after installation.  In my case it was this:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Alternatively, you can create symlinks for the utilities you need. E.g.:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/10.3/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql
```

**Note**: used installed version instead of 10.3.

Alternatively, you could instruct homebrew to "link all of its binaries to the PATH anyway"

```
 brew link --force libpq
```

but then you'd be unable to install the `postgresql` package later.

Comment: Works like a charm after creating symlink: ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/10.3/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql

Comment: You could also do `brew link --force libpq` but that will create a bunch of other symlinks you may not want/need.

Comment: symlinks du jour
 `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/11.3/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql`
/ `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/11.3/bin/pg_dump /usr/local/bin/pg_dump`
/ `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/11.3/bin/pg_restore /usr/local/bin/pg_restore`

Comment: Symlinks that do not depend on libpq version: `for cmd in psql pg_dump pg_restore; do ln -s ../opt/libpq/bin/$cmd /usr/local/bin/$cmd; done`

Comment: `PATH=/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH` to add all commands to your path in one go, using a directory name that doesn't change with the version of `libpq` that you install.

Comment: does this handle multiple different versions of postgresql?

Comment: @J.Wolfe kind of there's only one version in homebrew of libpq (i.e. the latest).  If you run ` brew search postgresql` it's got a few different older versions available, though they disappear over time...

Comment: Now that we're in M1 world, the correct path to binaries has changed and the command thus is `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: For M1 macs (insert your version of PSQL): `ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.0/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql`

Comment: which one is the better way? exporting PATH or creating symlinks?
it seems that the export operation needs to work on every terminal session, so it is an extra process, Am I right?

Comment: More simply, `sudo ln -s $(brew --prefix)/opt/libpq/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql`. Repeat for others, like `pg_dump`. And @SametBaskıcı -- I prefer symlinks so other non-terminal tools can use it (like Intellij DB connector with `pg_dump`).

Answer (score 122):

> libpq 11.2
> MacOS & zsh or bash

below works

1. install `libpq`

```bash
brew install libpq
```

2. update PATH

   if use zsh:

   ```bash
   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
   source ~/.zshrc

   # or on M1 MacOS
   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```

   if use bash:

   ```bash
   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```

Comment: `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` if you're using bash.

Comment: @HenryC yep, thanks, bash is much more common, my answer was based on zsh.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654216/correct-way-to-install-psql-without-full-postgres-on-macos#comment123605725_49689589) comment for Mac Mini M1 `PATH` variable.

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin` on M1 processor

Answer (score 71):

Homebrew only really has the **postgres** formula, and doesn't have any specific formula that only installs the `psql` tool.

So the "correct way" to get the `psql` application is indeed to install the **postgres** formula, and you'll see toward the bottom of the "caveats" section that it doesn't actually run the database, it just puts the files on your system:

```
$  brew install postgres
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/postgresql-9.6.5.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring postgresql-9.6.5.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.5/bin/initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
==> Caveats
<snip>
To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.5: 3,269 files, 36.7MB
```

Now you can use `psql` to connect to remote Postgres servers, and won't be running a local one, although you could if you really wanted to.

To verify that the local `postgres` daemon isn't running, check your installed homebrew services:

```
$ brew services list
Name       Status  User Plist
mysql      stopped      
postgresql stopped
```

If you don't have **Homebrew Services** installed, just

```
$ brew tap homebrew/services
```

...and you'll get this functionality. For more information on **Homebrew Services**, read [this excellent blog post that explains how it works](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which boils down to "how do I install psql (and maybe other postgres utilities) WITHOUT installing postgres". @PPS's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689589/2469559 is the correct one.

Comment: IMO, this is the better option because it doesn't require the `brew link` step. Forcing the link with libpq is necessary [due to the keg_only declaration](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/6a886b97fa4f04525bfeb3fb21c4b79c2ec92a12/Formula/libpq.rb#L13) in the formula. Given _this specific complication_, I stand by this answer as being the "correct" way to do what the question asks. I recognize that many users will still prefer the `libpq` approach though.

Comment: Yep this way doesn't require messing with symlinks or your PATH :)

Answer (score 68):

If you truly don't need postgresql then you don't even have to alter your path to use libra, just link `libpq`. The docs say the only reason it isn't is to avoid conflicts with the PostgreSQL package.

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install libpq
brew link --force libpq
```

Comment: I like that I don't have to create the symlink manually. This should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 47):

Install libpq:

```
 brew install libpq
```

Then, create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s $(brew --prefix)/opt/libpq/bin/psql /usr/local/bin/psql
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is the best answer because it's clear, to the point, and works independently of mac version.

Comment: I also managed to link `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` in the same way, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I found all of these really unsatisfying, especially if you have to support multiple versions of postgres.  A MUCH easier solution is to download the binaries here:

https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries

And simply run the executable version of `psql` that matches the database you're working against without any extra steps.

example:

```
./path/to/specific/version/bin/psql -c '\x' -c 'SELECT * FROM foo;'
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! For future reference, just download the version with the same major number (minor doesn't matter)

Comment: I  need only backup or restore DB. Easiest solution

Answer (score 4):

Found so many useful answers here, but a bit outdated since homebrew moved the installation files to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.1`. After libpq is installed with `brew install libpq` you can run below command to see new location

```html
brew link --force libpq
```

Then you can add it to your zshrc with

```html
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/15.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score -13):

You could try `brew install postgresql`

But this provides a nice GUI to manage your databases https://postgresapp.com

Comment: `brew install postgresql` install psql with database itself :(

Comment: It happens to also install `psql`, but, as a bonus, you don't have to mess with the PATH or symlinks...

Comment: There may be many reasons not to install full postgress. And the question was how to avoid installing it

Comment: PostgresApp is amazing and could be the answer if you choose to never initialize the database and use it just for the CLI tools.