# Rails - Gem Error while installing pg (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am still fairly new to Rails. I am trying to push to Heroku and I am getting errors.

The first error is when I run a Bundle Install I get this error message:

> "An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
> Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.3'` succeeds before bundling."

I have tried to run this command

```
gem install pg -v '1.1.3'
```

But it fails and gives me this error message:

> "ERROR:  Error installing pg:
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? As I recall, not all versions of the `pg` gem are compatible with all versions of Rails.

Comment: make sure you installed postresql on your machine

Comment: What OS are you using? If you are using a mac then you need to update XCode probably.

Comment: You may also need to stop and restart Postgres, or uninstall and reinstall it

Comment: I am using Rails 5.1.4

Comment: updating XCode would be going into terminal and running "softwareupdate --install --all", correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try instaling with pg-config like this:
`gem install pg -v 1.1.3 -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.X/bin/pg_config`.

In pg-config path mention the posgtres version installed in you're system.

Comment: I have version 10.0, can I ask you one more question? The correct command for 10.0 would be gem install pg -v 1.1.3 -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-10.0.X/bin/pg_config ?

Comment: `gem install pg -v 1.1.3 -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-10.0/bin/pg_config` without X

Comment: A variation that uses `which` to pass the path directly into the command:

`gem install pg -v 1.1.3 -- --with-pg-config=$(which pg_config)`

Note: you could also use backticks in place of the `$()`, but it's impossible hard to try and format a code block on SO with backticks (since the code marker uses backticks)

Answer (score 107):

I had the exact same problem, and solved it by running `sudo apt install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`. Then bundle worked just fine.

Comment: This worked for me! I should note that I am using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) - so for anyone facing similar issues with WSL, this does help fix it! :)

Comment: This works for me as well on Ubuntu 18.04 with Rails 6. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `sudo apt install libpq-dev` was sufficient for me

Comment: This works fine on Ubuntu 20.04 too

Comment: This fixed it for me too on Ubuntu 23.04 and Ruby 3.2

Answer (score 60):

if you're using OSX, you could try running

```
brew install postgresql
```

and then installing the gem

Answer (score 25):

**TL;DR;** If you installed the Postgres using the PostgresAPP instead of BREW then the problem might be that you don't have the Postgres bin folder in the $PATH

The solution is to find the Postgres app installation folder and the /bin folder in it.

In my case, if I run `which postgres` doesn't work which means I don't have it in my $PATH, so what I did is I navigated to: `cd /Applications/Postgres.app` then to `Contents` and then to `Versions` until I found the `latest` folder:

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Now, with this, I can install the PG GEM by providing the path to the bin folder of my Postgres app installation.

Finally, in the terminal at the root of my Rails project, I ran where I provided the postgres config file path to the GEM installer:

`gem install pg -v '1.2.3' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config`

Comment: thank you, this worked for me!

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the same problem. I am using Ubuntu. I installed Postgres using this [Ubuntu guide](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/). After installing Postgres, I ran this code `sudo apt install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev` then bundle install.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is not correct. If you installed postgresql-contrib and libpq-dev as mentioned in Cesar Faria answer, and you still getting the same error, most probable you missed the list of packages which are considered essential for building Debian packages. All that packages included in build-essential package. So, all you need to do to get rid of the error is the command below.

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev build-essential
```

Answer (score 7):

for me (macOS ventura, ruby 3) I needed to add psql first.

I basically followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689589/4883677

```
brew install libpq
brew link --force libpq
bundle install
```

Comment: linking was the issue for me in mac. even if you install it won't work unless you run the link command.

Answer (score 4):

Postgresql needs to be in local in order to install gem pg. Try this

```
brew install postgresql
```

and the re-install bundle

```
bundle install
```

or
If you are using yum. Try this

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is only for your local environment:

*Note: Update the command below to match your version `postgresql/13.2/...`*

```
> brew install postgres
> sudo gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.2/bin/pg_config
```

*Also, make sure to start your server `> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`*

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a little bit on **MacOS**. You want to:

```
brew formulae | grep postgresql@
```

Then pick a version from the list, and install it. For example:

```
brew install postgresql@12
```

Keep the note of installation instructions or open another tab in your terminal. There is a chance you gonna need them.

Then try to install this *gem* again:

```
bundle install pg
```

If this doesn't work, look at your post-install output from Homebrew. In my case I needed to do this:

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@12/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

(But I am using Zsh! If you're bash user, it's going to be different)

Now the command `bundle install pg` should work.

After that you can `bundle install` again.

And here is a hint from your fellow engineer. Did you know that if you run `bundle install -j 32` things are going to be a little bit faster? ;) Try this out!

If you still have failures, check out that they're related to `pg` gem. I am sorry if this was too hard, it shouldn't be that hard working with Rails! I wish you a good day!